# Angular ng-repeat animate position change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

If I have a list of divs generated by an `ng-repeat` directive:

```
<div class='carousel-item' ng-repeat="item in home.carouselItems">
    <img ng-src='{{item.icon}}' />
</div>
```

and every 2 seconds, in a controller directive I re-arrange the list of items:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    //timeout is needed so that the ng-repeat items can render
    $timeout(function(){
        $interval(function(){
            scope.home.carouselItems.push(scope.home.carouselItems.shift())
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

where the re-arrangement pops off the first item and appends it to the end, I want to animate the position change of the `div` elements. Visually, the divs are stacked like:

|Div 1|

|Div 2|

|Div 3|

etc

So Div 1 would be removed and appended to the end while Div 2 & 3 should animate their position up.

What I need is a pure-css way of animating not only the position change but also the opacity. So far I've been able to come up with:

```
&.ng-move,
&.ng-enter,
&.ng-leave {
    transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

&:nth-child(1) {
   &.ng-move.ng-move-active {
       opacity: 0.5;
   }
}
```

where `&` is the `.carousel-item` class.

There's a few issues. First, the `ng-repeat` items jump to their new spots with no position animation and then the opacity fade on the first element begins. Second, after the opacity animation completes, the item jumps back to it's original opacity of one.

What I'm trying to achieve is a carousel-like effect where the first item scrolls away and fades and THEN gets removed from the list, the second item fades to 0.5 opacity while moving the the first spot and so on forever.

I noticed something else interesting; I registered an animation for the `carousel-item` class and only `move` was called when I modified the array, not `leave` or `enter`. I suspect that's because I'm using `shift()`.